# NanoPi mali GPU doesn't want to increase frequency

Tags: hardware, arm, gpu

I'm trying to increase frequency of mali GPU on my NanoPi M4.

I use friendlyarm-desktop distro.

The `/sys/class/misc/mali0/device/devfreq/ff9a0000.gpu/governor` is already in "performance" mode.

But `/sys/class/misc/mali0/device/devfreq/ff9a0000.gpu/max_freq` is only `200000000`, when `/sys/class/misc/mali0/device/devfreq/ff9a0000.gpu/available_frequencies` is `800000000 600000000 400000000 300000000 200000000`.

I change it to `600000000`, but after few seconds it starts to change to `200000000` and to `600000000` again randomly.

How can I fix it with my value? Is it changed by some process? How can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with heating. CPU temperature was 69-70 (got it with this command:

```
echo $((`cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` / 1000))
```

from
gramian/neotemp/[Read CPU temperature of Nanopi Neo](https://gist.github.com/gramian/76a1806cdf76ce62a3f18147d31bc84d).

I don't know how but system decreased GPU maximal frequency when temperature was 70 degrees and increased when it was lower. So, with my temperature, frequency jumped to 200 and to 600 MHz frequently.